# PostgreSQL - Ordering Jumbled Data (Recursive?)

Tags: postgresql

I have some unordered data in a PostgreSQL database that looks like this:

```
ID  PATH    START   END
7   A123    B       C
4   B456    D       E
9   A123    A       B
2   B456    A       B
6   B456    B       C
21  A123    C       D
3   B456    C       D
5   B456    E       F
```

*START and END values can't be ordered alphabetically, these have just been used to illustrate the issue*

I am trying to achieve this:

```
id  path    sequence    start   end
9   A123    1           A       B
7   A123    2           B       C
21  A123    3           C       D
2   B456    1           A       B
6   B456    2           B       C
3   B456    3           C       D
4   B456    4           D       E
5   B456    5           E       F
```

The logic I am thinking of to achieve this to determine the start value (represented as A) for each path (A123 / B456). Then determine the sequence AB, BC, CD etc). Which needs to be repeated for all paths.

I've written recursive query that iterates through a given path name (See WHERE path = 'B456')

```
WITH RECURSIVE ordered(id, path, sequence, "start", "end") AS (
WITH path AS (SELECT id, "path", "start", "end"
FROM unordered
WHERE path = 'B456'),
startofpath AS (SELECT p1.id
FROM unordered p1
LEFT JOIN unordered p2 ON p1.start = p2.end
WHERE p2.start IS NULL)

--find start of path (A)
SELECT path.id, path.path, 1, path.start, path.end
FROM path, startofpath
WHERE path.id = startofpath.id
UNION ALL
--add on next path (B -> C)
SELECT path.id, path.path, ordered.sequence + 1, path.start, path.end FROM 
path
INNER JOIN ordered
ON path.start = ordered."end")
SELECT * FROM ordered
```

Sample Data:

```
CREATE table unordered (
id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
path TEXT NOT NULL,
"start" TEXT NOT NULL,
"end" TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (7,'A123','B','C');
INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (4,'B456','D','E');
INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (9,'A123','A','B');
INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (2,'B456','A','B');
INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (6,'B456','B','C');
INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (21,'A123','C','D');
INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (3,'B456','C','D');
INSERT INTO unordered (id, path, "start", "end") VALUES (5,'B456','E','F');
```

What I am having trouble solving is then how to iterate through all paths (A123, then B456 etc)

Is anyone able to assist with this next step?
(or reworking my query from scratch if I've got the complete wrong idea)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
WITH RECURSIVE
get_path(id, path, sequence, starting, ending) AS (
    SELECT u.id, u.path, 1, u.starting, u.ending 
    FROM unordered AS u
    WHERE u.starting NOT IN (SELECT u.ending FROM unordered AS u) -- a starting point has no entry in ending column

    UNION

    SELECT u.id, u.path, g.sequence + 1, g.ending, u.ending
    FROM get_path AS g, unordered AS u
    WHERE u.starting = g.ending
)
TABLE get_path ORDER BY path, sequence;
```

Please note that i changed `"start"` into `starting` and `"end"` into `ending`.

Comment: Close, in my query I fixed the path as a constant value, in your query you've fixed the start as 'A'.


What I'm having trouble with is the combination of the two.


For each path find the correct order of it's child records when the start is unknown (but can be derived because B -> C joins to A -> B but A -> B does not join to anything)

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: That's great! Thanks Tony!